# DocumentClient binding in parameter of Azure function

Tags: azure, f#, azure-functions, azure-webjobssdk, azure-cosmosdb

I am writing an http trigger Azure function in F# and I would like to bind a parameter of type `DocumentClient` to have more control on the queries that are done in Cosmos DB. This is what I have so far:

Function.fs

```
namespace Functions

open System
open System.Net
open System.Net.Http
open Newtonsoft.Json
open Microsoft.Azure.Documents
open Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client
open Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs
open Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host
open Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions
open Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB

module Function = 
  let Run(req: HttpRequestMessage, [<DocumentDB>] client: DocumentClient, log: TraceWriter) =
    log.Info(sprintf "F# HTTP trigger function processed a request.")
    req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK)
```

function.json

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "..\\..\\..\\build\\Debug\\Functions\\Functions.dll",
  "entryPoint": "Functions.Function.Run",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [ "get" ],
      "route": "users"
    },
    {
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "documentDB",
      "name": "client",
      "connection": "COSMOSDB_CONNECTION_STRING"
    },
    {
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "http",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

host.json

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Dynamitey": "1.0.2",
        "FSharp.Interop.Dynamic": "3.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB": "1.17.0",
        "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB": "1.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "COSMOSDB_CONNECTION_STRING": "AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:8081;AccountKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==;"
  }
}
```

I am runnning the function locally using the development storage and Cosmos DB emulator. I tried to translate to F# what it is described [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions#documentdb) for C#. And it is also pretty much the same as what is mentioned [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/984). But I only get the error `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB: 'Id' is required when binding to a DocumentClient property`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a workaround mentioned in [this issue on Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1783#issuecomment-322317383). It's fixed in the [tooling](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/issues/206) and will be available with the next release

*workaround copied from github*

> I found the issue and filed
> https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/issues/206. The easiest
> workaround until we have an update:
>
> Go to `C:\Users\{user}\appdata\local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.0`.
>
> Open `func.exe.config` in notepad.
>
> Find this:
>
> ```
> <dependentAssembly>
>   <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
>     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.11.0.0" newVersion="1.11.0.0" />
> </dependentAssembly>
> ```
>
> In both places, replace `1.11.0.0` with `1.13.0.0` so you end up with:
>
> ```
> <dependentAssembly>
>     <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
>     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.13.0.0" newVersion="1.13.0.0" />
>   </dependentAssembly>
> ```
>
> Save and retry.

Comment: Yes, this works.Thanks! I had installed Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB v.1.17 so I needed to downgrade to v.1.13.

Comment: Hm. wonder what we're supposed to do if we're getting this error from w/in the Functions IDE on the Portal...